# Do VB class level variables persist in various functions and subs throughout that class?

Tags: vb.net, class, variables

Consider this class:

```
Public Class MyClass
Dim MyVar as New Note

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        MyVar.ID = 1
        MyVar.Name = "Smith"
    End Sub

    Protected Sub saveBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles saveBtn.Click
        newVar = MyVar
    End Sub
End Class
```

I think that in this example, I should be able to read newVar.ID = 1 and newVar.Name = "Smith".

However, this is not what happens.

Do the variables not persist within the class?

Comment: 'MyVar' is accessible throughout the class. 'newVar' isn't declared at all (unless you left out the declaration) and so the code won't event compile unless you have `Option Explicit Off`. If you don't declare `newVar` outside the `saveBtn_Click` method, it will only be accessible inside that method.

Comment: `Page_Load` is an interesting choice of name ... are you making a Windows application or a web page? (Because I'm wondering if you're doing ASP.NET stuff, and if so, that might explain things...)

Comment: Scott--assuming that this is an ASP.NET page, when saveBtn is clicked, it is running in a new instance of MyClass, so whatever MyVar was previously is gone.  If you want to set a variable when the page is loaded, and then access that data when the button is clicked, there are several ways to do it, such as session variables.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561604/how-to-create-instance-of-a-class-only-once-in-asp-net